# How to get rid of Spaces between logs when using 'logrus' package

Tags: go

So I started using 'logrus'.
I set it in my own logger package which looks like this:

```
    package logger

import(
     log "github.com/Sirupsen/logrus"

)


func InitLogger() {
    var textFormatter = new(log.TextFormatter)
    textFormatter.TimestampFormat = "2006-01-02 15:04:05"
    textFormatter.ForceColors = true
    textFormatter.FullTimestamp = true

    log.SetFormatter(textFormatter)
}


func Printf(format string, v ...interface{}) {
    log.Printf(format, v...)
}

func Fatalf(format string, v ...interface{}) {
    log.Fatalf(format, v...)
}

func Panicf(format string, v ...interface{}) {
    log.Panicf(format, v...)
}

func Debugf(format string, v ...interface{}) {
    log.Debugf(format, v...)
```

(it goes like this for all logrus log functions, dont see the 
   point of pasting all of them here, but you get the idea...)

Use it across my project as:

```
import(
    log "logger"
)
```

And everything is peachy except logs being printed with line spaces between them:

```
INFO[2016-04-16 17:32:51] pathPrefix: /app/
pathValue: {js ./app/}

INFO[2016-04-16 17:32:51] pathPrefix: /node_modules/
pathValue: {js ./node_modules/}

INFO[2016-04-16 17:32:51] Listening for HTTP on tcp (0.0.0.0:8080)     
INFO[2016-04-16 17:38:02] Starting HomeHandler                         
INFO[2016-04-16 17:38:02] GET / Index 4.769735ms

INFO[2016-04-16 17:38:02] Starting AuthCheckHandler                    
ERRO[2016-04-16 17:38:02] Failed getting cookie from user: http: named cookie not present

INFO[2016-04-16 17:38:02] GET /auth AuthCheckHandler 67.79µs

INFO[2016-04-16 17:38:02] Starting AuthCheckHandler                    
ERRO[2016-04-16 17:38:02] Failed getting cookie from user: http: named cookie not present

INFO[2016-04-16 17:38:02] GET /auth AuthCheckHandler 82.195µs
```

How can I get rid of those spaces? 
Couldn't find any solution in documentation/google nor here
so I assume its something very silly that I am missing...

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like you are passing newlines when you pass your string formatting.

```
func main() {

  x := 0
  logger.InitLogger()

  logger.Printf("%s", "TEST1")
  logger.Printf("%s", "TEST2")

  if x == 0 {
      logger.Printf("%s", "TEST3")
      logger.Printf("%s", "TEST4")
      logger.Printf("%s", "TEST5")
  }
}
```

Returns:

```
go run main.go
INFO[2016-04-16 12:40:30] TEST1
INFO[2016-04-16 12:40:30] TEST2
INFO[2016-04-16 12:40:30] TEST3
INFO[2016-04-16 12:40:30] TEST4
INFO[2016-04-16 12:40:30] TEST5
```

Comment: I do @Stantonnet. as I used original go "log" package and all of my logs ended with `\n` for example: `log.Printf("Failed do somthing with error: %s\n", err)` did not realized logrus is taking care of new lines by it self. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you aren't accidentally including new lines in some of the messages you are sending to your logger package?